# Why when I add a certain number of controls to the flowLayoutPanel added more than the desired in c #?

Tags: c#

When tried to use method to add UserControl in flowLayoutPanel1

Get a number of more than required controls

```
public void count_rows_columns()
    {
        // delete All UserControls
        foreach (Control clear in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<latest>())
        {
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(clear);
        }

        #region set latest bord


        decimal space_between_2columns =0;
        decimal count_rows = 0;
        decimal count_columns = 0;

         space_between_2columns = Convert.ToDecimal(((flowLayoutPanel1.Width - 1000) / 3));
         count_rows = ((flowLayoutPanel1.Height) / 145);
         count_columns = ((flowLayoutPanel1.Width) / 500);

        silk_section.Text = count_rows.ToString();



    if ((int)count_columns == 1)
        {
                                //count_rows here will be 4
            for (int C_rows = 0; C_rows < count_rows; C_rows++)
                {


                    latest latest1 = new latest();
                    latest1.Name = String.Concat("latest1_", (C_rows +1).ToString());
                    latest1.Left = ((flowLayoutPanel1.Width - latest1.Width) / 2);
                    latest1.Top = (latest1.Height * C_rows) + 32;

                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(latest1);

                }

        }
}
```

When count_rows equals 3 I get 4 and When count_rows equals 4 I get 7

but i want get 4 if count_rows equals 4

Comment: remove `C_rows +1` and replace with just `C_rows` the math is going to loop 4 times because C_rows is starting at 0 in your conditional. For example 4 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 7. the 0/1/1/1 is each loop.

Comment: @xTwisteDx That `C_rows +1` is just for setting the name. It's not altering `C_rows` or affecting the  number of times looped at all. It just makes it so the the names start at `latest1_1` instead of `latest1_0`.

Comment: @itsme86 I feel certain that it's referring to the text rather than the actual math. I see no math there that relates to 4==7 other than the text. The rest of the math is formatting, unless I'm looking past something here.

Comment: @xTwisteDx removed `latest1.Name = String.Concat("latest1_", (C_rows +1).ToString());` The problem has not been resolved

Comment: you commented it out and it still throws the same error?

Comment: if tried print `C_rows` value will 1,3,0,1,2,3 if `count_rows`value equal `3`

Comment: Are you sure your code is clearing out all the existing controls? In VB.NET, the FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Clear method is available. I'm sure it's the same in C#?

Comment: @HardCode Used `foreach` for clear all UserControl exsits in it

Comment: @Geanny did you confirm it's actually clearing all the controls before adding the new ones?

Comment: Is this method being called from an event handler?

Comment: @HardCode yes i did

Comment: @ChrisDunaway no

Answer (score 0):

Removed `(C_Rows + 1)`, changed conditional to say `C_rows = 1` so that your `.ToString` will output 1-4. It should now output whatever goes in.

```
for (int C_rows = 1; C_rows <= count_rows; C_rows++)
                {


                    latest latest1 = new latest();
                    latest1.Name = String.Concat("latest1_", (C_rows).ToString());
                    latest1.Left = ((flowLayoutPanel1.Width - latest1.Width) / 2);
                    latest1.Top = (latest1.Height * C_rows) + 32;

                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(latest1);
```

Comment: it still throws the same error,and i get 6 UserControls when `count_rows` value equal `3`